# Add currency symbol at right or left

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

How to add a currency symbol at right if the input is `€` or left is the input is `$`? Is there a pipe for it or something else?

That is the pipe I wrote but the user can enter letter that is what I want to avoid, or 000.

```js
transform(value: unknown, currencySymbol: string):unknown {
    let stringValue = <string>value;

    if (!stringValue) {
      stringValue = currencySymbol + ' 0';
    }

    if (stringValue.charAt(0) === currencySymbol) {
      return currencySymbol + ' ' + stringValue.replace(currencySymbol, '').trim();
    } else 
    {
      return currencySymbol + ' ' + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular currency pipe already does that based on locale data. In order to use it, you need to add the localize features first:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

Then, you have to register all the locales you need in app.module.ts. Note that the register function has to be called directly (not inside the module constructor):

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import de from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(de, 'de');
```

You can use the currency pipe like this:

```
{{ 9999.99 | currency }} <br/>
{{ 9999.99 | currency: "EUR" : "symbol" : undefined : "de" }}
```

Output:

```
$9,999.99
9.999,99 €
```

Remarks:

- Notice that automatically not only the position of the currency
  symbol has changed, but also other things like the decimal separate
  (. or ,). So it makes absolutely sense to use the localize features
  of Angular here instead of re-inventing the wheel.
- Your question indicates that your currency values already contains a currency symbol. You should try to refactor that. Add a separate currency selector if possible. Our you maybe could implement a separate filter that extracts the currency symbol.

Comment: what do you understand hier please: Note that the register function has to be called directly (not inside the module constructor):

Comment: @Elvisaldo, just put the line registerLocaleData(de, 'de') directly beneath the input statements and before the module/component code. So, just like it is shown in the code snippet.